# How to set text depth=0pt for multiline text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I would like to place a multiline text (w/o a priori knowledge of the
number of lines) with zero depth. When n = 1 the solution is easy (`text depth = 0pt`), but with n > 1 this does not work properly. What do I have to do to achieve the wanted effect?

In the second part of the example the baseline of the text is identical
with the line drawn. In the third example I would like to get the same,
but here are the descenders on the line drawn.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]
 \draw (0,0) -- (5,0);
 \node[text width=5cm,above] at (2.5,0)
    {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, };

 \begin{scope}[yshift=3cm]
    \draw (0,0) -- (5,0);
    \node[text width=5cm,text depth=0pt,above] at (2.5,0)
       {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, };
 \end{scope}

 \begin{scope}[yshift=6cm]
    \draw (0,0) -- (5,0);
    \node[text width=5cm,text depth=0pt,above] at (2.5,0)
       {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, };
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TX.SX! I've include the result of your code. From it I don't understand the question, could you better explain what you want to obtain? By the way, take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided

Comment: Can you manually draw it and upload what you want exactly? so that one can understand the question.

Comment: @ Ignasi: Thanks for adding the picture.  @David: I have added another sentence to hopefully clarify my aim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image]

If yes, the solution is a node with `inner sep=-depth("p")`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]
 \draw (0,0) -- (5,0);
 \node[text width=5cm,above, inner sep=-depth("p")] at (2.5,0)
    {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is (nearly) exactly what I want. Many thanks for that idea! It is even better for me to set `above=-depth("p")` (with `inner sep` I change the distance in all four directions). The only small problem is, that this also causes a shift when there is no descender in the text; but if I add a `\vphantom{q}` ...

Comment: @Jürgen Glad to help you. Yes `inner sep` changes inner margin, but you can also use `inner xsep` or `inner ysep` which affect only to inner  horizontal o vertical distance between node text and border.

Comment: Ok, good to know. But I think and hope that the approach with `above` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, when `textwidth` is used the `minipage` installed before the node contents uses the `[t]` option and this is not customizable. However, this customization can be more-or-less successfully achieved using the `execute at begin node` and `execute at end node` keys:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\tikzset{minipage/.style 2 args={%
  execute at begin node=\begin{minipage}[#1]{#2}\raggedright,
  execute at end node=\end{minipage},
  anchor=base
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0);
\node[minipage={b}{5cm}] at (2.5,0) {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet};

\tikzset{shift=(270:2)}
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0);
\node[minipage={b}{5cm}] at (2.5,0) {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
  consectetuer adipiscing elit};

\tikzset{shift=(270:2)}
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0);
\node[minipage={b}{5cm}] at (2.5,0) {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
  consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Mark, for this canonic solution. I must admit that the other solution is, at least for me, a bit simpler to use. But I will have a closer look at the `execute at begin/end node` options.